# Single endpoint in outbound message on different objects

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I have implemented the outbound message approach  to integrate with external system on one sObject. But now, I would like to reuse the same logic and would like to keep the same endpoint to send notifications on different objects.

Please let me know if its feasible with OM or not?

Regards,
Poonam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same endpoint for multiple outbound messages (Since the endpoint is defined on a per message basis) as long as the endpoint supports receiving multiple types.

Comment: In terms of implementation, do we need to add notification wsdl of different objects in outbound message handler?